# Need a macro in opencalc

Tags: openoffice.org

I need some assistance on a macro to in openoffice.
The idea is to have 2 macros. 1 to password protect a sheet and another to reprotect the sheet.
Will provide more info provided someone can assist me.
Thank you

Tried a macro but giving me errors

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please search online before asking here. I entered "apache openoffice macro password protect sheet" in Google and it gave the following first result: https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=78225. If you tried code like that and got errors, then please post the code giving the error along with the error message, and include your operation system and version of LibreOffice or AOO (but your tag of "openoffice.org" is incorrect unless your system has not been updated in many years, and if so, please upgrade before doing anything else).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.